# differences between prototype and namespace

Tags: javascript

In namespace we can use something like this:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.something.nested.namespacing();
```

And also in prototype we can use same like name the namespace:

```
something.prototype.method();
```

In both types we are using `. notation`. So, how can we determine the code is using namespace or prototype?

Comment: Can you include a more *real* example, and possibly add *why* you need to determine this? In the code you provided the difference is obvious as the second case includes "`prototype`".

Comment: There are no namespaces in JavaScript. You can *simulate* namespaces using JavaScript objects.

Comment: There is no "namespace" here. Property lookup is on the object first, then its private `[[Prototype]]`, then that object's `[[Prototype]]` and so on. The object path in the accessing expression is irrelevant to how property lookup proceeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have namespaces. What you're calling a namespace is just an object. It's fairly common to use objects to stand in for namespaces.

Your code:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.something.nested.namespacing();
```

...creates an *object* and a variable that refers to that object called `namespace`. Then you add properties to that object (it looks like you've added a property, `something`, which is also an object, which has a property, `nested`, which is *also* an object, which has a property called `namespacing` which refers to a function).

Your code:

```
something.prototype.method();
```

...is also using an object. The above would actually be a really unusual thing to do, you're calling a function (`method`) by directly referring to the `prototype` property of what I assume is a function (`something`). That's not normally what you would do. Normally you'd create an object via the function:

```
var s = new something();
```

...and then use the prototype that got assigned to `s` implicitly:

```
s.method();
```

The `prototype` property on functions can be confusing to people new to JavaScript. It's just a normal property like any other property, which is on function instances. The only thing that makes it special is the `new` operator: When you call a function via `new`:

```
var s = new something();
```

...the JavaScript engine creates a new, blank, object, then sets its underlying prototype (sometimes called `__proto__` but that's not in the spec [yet]) using `something.prototype`, like this:

```
// pseudo-code for `var s = new something()`
var tmp = {};                        // New, blank object
tmp.__proto__ = something.prototype; // Assign a prototype to the new object
something.call(tmp);                 // Call `something` with `this` referring to `tmp`
s = tmp;                             // Assign the result to `s`
```

*(There's a detail I left out in the above to avoid confusing matters, to do with the special case where `something` has an explicit `return` statement in it that returns an object reference.)*

Answer (score 4):

Well, namespaces are just objects and prototype objects are objects, so from a syntactic point of view, there is no difference how you access them (`foo.bar` is called *dot notation(*).

However, they serve two fundamentally different purposes:

- Namespaces are used to structure your code and to avoid global namespace pollution.
- Prototypes are used to share methods between multiple instances of the same constructor function.

So you usually don't call a method directly on the prototype because it most likely won't work. The purpose of this method is to be called on an instance of the corresponding constructor function. For example:

```
function Something() {}
Something.prototype.foo = function() {};

var s = new Something();
s.foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.` notation is a very general purpose tool used in javascript for accessing any properties of any object.

```
var x = {};
x.val = 2;
```

Your reference to a namespace is just a general purpose object in javascript as there is no actual namespace type in javascript.  In other words, plain objects are used to create namespace-like things in javascript.  So, as such, object properties are used to keep track of names in the namespace.

---

The `.` notation's use with the prototype is one specific instance of accessing properties on a specific type of object (the prototype).  A prototype is used on a function object and has a very specific use when creating new instances of that function.

```
function foo() {
}

foo.prototype.talk = function() {
    alert("hello");
}

var y = new foo();
y.talk();
```

Comment: It means we could only use prototypes only for function object not other types. Thanks.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar: No, all objects have a prototype. It's easy to do, but don't confuse the `prototype` property on functions (which is **not** the function's prototype) and the prototype of an object (which is **not** called `prototype`; it has no externally-visible name at the moment, but in ES6 it will be called `__proto__`). The `prototype` property of a function is a reference to an object that will get assigned to objects created if you use that function with the `new` operator.